# Best way to obtain geocode for location, in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, twitter, geocoding

Ok
quite frustrated by Twitter search api for location based searches.
In  the advanced search page you can specify 'near' a specific location and this 'near' parameter shows up clearly in the query string.

However, Twitter does not support the use of 'near' in the public search api.

Apparently you need to supply a geocode value.

Can anyone suggest the best way for obtaining a geocode in Flash?

Comment: apparently the choice is between Google, MapQuest, and Yahoo! anyone care to make a recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I've used yahoo and googlemap, and out of the two, I would rather work with the google API
But both will get you there.

Also, you might want to expand on what output you are trying to get from what input, as there may be other ways.